# I want to get the current position of an ImageIcon on a JPanel(Java)

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, keyevent, imageicon

I want to get the coordinate of an image so I can change the background color of the JPanel relative to the coordinates. Here is what I have so far. The code allows the user to move a arrow up, down, right and left, so if the arrow if a the first quadrant the background should be red, if the arrow is moved to the second quadrant the background changes color to green and so on

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class DirectionPanel extends JPanel
{
   private final int X = 200;
   private Point point = null;

   private final int WIDTH = 400, HEIGHT = 200;
   private final int JUMP = 10;  // increment for image movement

   private final int IMAGE_SIZE = 31;

   private ImageIcon up, down, right, left, currentImage;
   private int x, y;

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Constructor: Sets up this panel and loads the images.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public DirectionPanel()
   {
      addKeyListener (new DirectionListener());

      x = WIDTH / 2;
      y = HEIGHT / 2;

      up = new ImageIcon ("arrowUp.gif");
      down = new ImageIcon ("arrowDown.gif");
      left = new ImageIcon ("arrowLeft.gif");
      right = new ImageIcon ("arrowRight.gif");

      currentImage = right;

      setBackground (Color.black);
      setPreferredSize (new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
      setFocusable(true);
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Draws the image in the current location.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public void paintComponent (Graphics page)
   {
      super.paintComponent (page);
      currentImage.paintIcon (this, page, x, y);
   }

   //*****************************************************************
   //  Represents the listener for keyboard activity.
   //*****************************************************************
   private class DirectionListener implements KeyListener
   {
      //--------------------------------------------------------------
      //  Responds to the user pressing arrow keys by adjusting the
      //  image and image location accordingly.
      //--------------------------------------------------------------
      public void keyPressed (KeyEvent event)
      {
         switch (event.getKeyCode())
         {
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                currentImage = up;
                y -= JUMP;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                currentImage = down;
                y += JUMP;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                currentImage = left;
                x -= JUMP;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                currentImage = right;
                x += JUMP;
                break;
         }

         point = ???????

         if(point.x < 200 && point.y < 100)
         {
            setBackground(Color.red);
         }
         else if(point.x < 200 && point.y > 100)
         {
            setBackground(Color.green);
         }
         else if(point.y > 100 && point.x > 200)
         {
            setBackground(Color.cyan);
         }
         else if(point.y < 100 && point.x > 200)
         {
            setBackground(Color.yellow);
         }

         repaint();
      }

      //--------------------------------------------------------------
      //  Provide empty definitions for unused event methods.
      //--------------------------------------------------------------
      public void keyTyped (KeyEvent event) {}
      public void keyReleased (KeyEvent event) {}
   }
}
```

Comment: `point = new Point(x, y);` ??

Comment: ImageIcons don't have a location property

Comment: Thanks you. It works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use your variables: "x" and "y" to draw the image so those variables would be the coordinates of your image in your JPanel.

You can set your point to:

```
    point = new Point(x, y);
```

Now when you update your "x" and "y" the point will also be updated and the background will draw according to your specifications.

I hope it helps!